# Fullpage js blur transition between horizontal slides

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Does anyone know how to edit the below code to make the transition between horizontal slides more like a blur rather than a fade? Im trying to make it feel like you are leaving a "room" and entering another "room" when you scroll between horizontal slides, so a blur effect or anything similar would work better than fadeIn. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0hLzxrea/28/) codepen.

```js
var SCROLLING_SPEED = 200;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        verticalCentered: false,
        anchors:['section1'],
      
        // fullPage.js settings for fading-in slides insead of scrolling them.
        // Disable or nullify scrolling of slides
   
        
        // Hide the slides container before the next slide loads
        onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {
            $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(0);
            $('.fp-section').find('.fp-slidesContainer').hide();
        },
      
        // Display the slides container by fading it in after the next slide has been loaded.
        afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
            $('.fp-section').find('.fp-slidesContainer').fadeIn(800);
            $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(SCROLLING_SPEED);
        }
        
     });
});

$(document).ready(function(){

      $(".button1").click(function() {
      $.fn.fullpage.moveTo('section1', 1); 
      $('.fp-section').find('.fp-slidesContainer').hide(); //hide current slide
    });
    
    $(".button2").click(function() {
      $.fn.fullpage.moveTo('section1', 2);
      $('.fp-section').find('.fp-slidesContainer').hide(); //hide current slide
    });
    
    $(".button3").click(function() {
      $.fn.fullpage.moveTo('section1', 3);
      $('.fp-section').find('.fp-slidesContainer').hide(); //hide current slide
    });


});
```

```css
    /* Style for our header texts
    * --------------------------------------- */
    h1{
        font-size: 5em;
        font-family: arial,helvetica;
        color: #fff;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    /* Centered texts in each section
    * --------------------------------------- */
    .section{
        text-align:center;
    }


    /* Backgrounds will cover all the section
    * --------------------------------------- */
    .section{
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .slide{
        background-size: cover;
    }


    /*Adding background for the slides
    * --------------------------------------- */
    #slide1{
        background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/examples/imgs/bg2.jpg);
        padding: 6% 0 0 0;
    }
    #slide2, #slide3, #slide4{
        background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/examples/imgs/bg5.jpg);
        padding: 6% 0 0 0;
    }


    /* Bottom menu
    * --------------------------------------- */
    #infoMenu li a {
        color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class="slide" id="slide1">
        <h1>Index</h1>
        <button class="button1">
          Slide 1
        </button>
        <button class="button2">
          Slide 2
        </button>
        <button class="button3">
          Slide 3
        </button>
       </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide2"><h1>First Slide</h1></div>
      <div class="slide" id="slide3"><h1>Second Slide</h1></div>
      <div class="slide" id="slide4"><h1>Third Slide</h1></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without fullpage.js won't do?

Comment: Technically it doesnt matter but using fullpage.js makes my life a whole lot easier design wise! Is there something I can do with `onSlideLeave` and `afterSlideLoad` ?

Comment: ive managed to almost get the effect i want using the following CSS...but the filter blur effect is being applied always rather than on scroll. Can you see from the below code why thats happening?

`.fp-slide {
    opacity: 0.3 !important;
              -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    transition: all 4s ease-in-out !important;
}

.fp-slide.active {
    opacity: 1 !important;
              -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
        transition: all 4s ease-in-out !important;

}`

Comment: That's because CSS filters lack "directionality" they always blur as circles try SVG filters instead. That would help blur along axis so it would feel as if it's moving along horizontal

Comment: ive seen another https://codepen.io/CSobol/pen/LGCiw with a blur on hover transition, so surely it can be applied to a section when it becomes active/inactive?

Comment: They are using `img.blur:hover` (hover css selector) but sure you can use some class say "blurit" there and add that class to get that effect when the slide change happens

Comment: cool, as the opacity transition is working on the code above i think that fullpage.js is adding and removing "active" on scroll already, so the filter: blur property should be working as well, thats why im confused.

Comment: Looks like the inbuilt fade effect comes from css (inline) manipulation through javascript and not some static css you can see it happen in devtools when slide is in transition . So fp must be resetting all the transition css that's why yours isn' t working

Comment: figured it out! thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SVG filter](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_filters_intro.asp) along the horizontal axis

Add this SVG before your slide divs

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="filters">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur">  <-- id is blur
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15,0" />
      <!-- 1st param is how much spread you need along the on X axis  -->
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="slide" id="slide2"><h1>First Slide</h1></div>
<!-- others hidden -->
```

Read more on `<feGaussianBlur>` over [here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_fegaussianblur.asp)

And script

```
onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {
    $('.slide').css({
        webkitFilter:'url(#blur)', //blur is id of SVG filter elment
        filter:'url(#blur)'
    });
},


afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slide').css({
        webkitFilter:'none', //removes the filter
        filter:'none'
      })
  }, 200);
}
```